# PHP Crawler for a asp.net site

Tags: php, web-crawler

I wanna write a crawler to fetch data. from an asp.net site which uses javascript to do the pagination

Comment: You are aware that their T&C state `You agree not to reproduce, duplicate, copy, sell, resell or exploit for any commercial purposes, any portion of the Service, use of the Service, or access to the Service` ?

Comment: Why would you like to get contents from a 3rd party website? You'd better to ask them for permission / the contents before creating a crawler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CURL Library](http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to get html code of each page, then you must only parse this pages.
For other type of page you must write other parser, do it on a [DOM Library](http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) then parsers will have few lines for each type of page.

**But you must have permission to do this, you must ask the author of agree of what you doing.**